# How can I use a set state without stateful widget and I am using a search delegate in flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

what I want to do is that my search history can update it,
I can´t delete a previous search with click on the delete icon
but I want to use the set state but it gives me an error and the reason may be that I am not using a StatefulWiget because I am using a Search delegate.
I would appreciate the help.
Code::

```
 class SearchDelegateMenuPrincipal  extends SearchDelegate<SearchDelegateModel>{
    
      @override
      final String searchFieldLabel;
       List<SearchDelegateModel> historialMenuPrincipal=[];
       SearchDelegateModel busquedaa;
      final menuprincipalservices = new MenuPrincipalServices();
      SearchDelegateMenuPrincipal(this.searchFieldLabel,this.historialMenuPrincipal);
      @override
      List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
       //code
      }
    
      @override
      Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
       //code
        ),
    
      );
      }
    
    @override
      Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
       //code
      }
    
     @override
      Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
        return HistorialBusquedaSuggestions(this.historialMenuPrincipal );
      }
    
    
     Widget HistorialBusquedaResults(List <SearchDelegateModel> BusquedaHistorial ){
     //code
      }
    
     Widget HistorialBusquedaSuggestions(List <SearchDelegateModel> historialMenuPrincipal ){
    
    
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            color: Colors.white
          ),
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: historialMenuPrincipal.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,i){
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12,horizontal: 16);
                leading:CircleAvatar(
                radius: 32,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                "https://9.bp.blogspot.com/-3ZzNZsjQk/WR94I4II/AAAAAAAAAJw/_inTVynS60V75IZ-461-paWArTSwCEw/s1600/ANA.jpg"),
                );
    
                return ListTile(
                   title: Text(historialMenuPrincipal[i].email?? "no hay data"),
       
                  trailing: IconButton(
                   icon: Icon(Icons.cancel,color: Colors.black,),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState((context) {
       busqueda.remove(busqueda[]); // i want to use this
                      });
                
                    
                      
                    },
                  ),
              
                );
              }
          ),
    
        );
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, That's the whole point of `Stateless` and `Stateful` widgets. Only `Stateful` has this `setState()`

There's some other method, which goes like:

```dart
(context as Element).markNeedsBuild();
```

Pass this at some button press, although its from flutter 1.x something version.

Comment: it works but better is to use a statefulbuilder

Comment: `StatefulBuilder` is extends as `StatefulWidget`, hence the point remains the same you can't use setState without using Stateful widget